# Is it possible to use tlc while do stateflow design in MATLAB Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow, tlc

The tlc can be saved as text file and has tracebilty.

Is it possible to using tlc in stateflow design?
Or Any other suggestion to keep the tracebilty feature in sateflow project?

Comment: i mean use .m files not tlc files.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean m-code, and not tlc, then please edit your question to say m-code and remove all mention of tlc.

Can you use m-code in Stateflow? -- yes.  See [MATLAB Functions in a Stateflow Chart](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/matlab-functions-in-a-stateflow-chart.html) for an exmaple.

However, if you're doing code generation (and using the traceability features) then you have the same limitations on the use of m-code as you do with any use of Simulink Coder (or Embedded Coder).

There is a brief description of what the generated code will look like for a MATLAB Function block within Stateflow in the doc: [Trace Stateflow elements in Generated Code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/trace-stateflow-elements-in-generated-code.html#brhfb0t-22).